# Jquery Load more and hide button

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of article thnumbnail on my project website.
I'm trying to make jquery show more button for article thumbnails and when all content is loaded, I need to hide all articles except the first three with the same or another button, as they are when the site is loaded.

My code so far look like this and I don't know what to do next. Thanks for any help.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $(".more-box").slice(0, 3).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".more-box:hidden").slice(0, 3).fadeIn();
      if ($(".more-box:hidden").length == 0) {
        // ON CLICK HIDE ALL ARTICLES EXCEPT FIRST THREE
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="articles">
  <div class="wrapper more-content">
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=26">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/c4slrsw6a680840g40.jpeg" alt="ov-a: Pedantný proces navrhovania v kombinácii s dialógom s klientom" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">ov-a: Pedantný proces navrhovania v kombinácii s dialógom s klientom</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=24">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/71c2l0vfphwc40c40s.jpeg" alt="SINGULARCH: ov–a (Praha, CZ)" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">SINGULARCH: ov–a (Praha, CZ)</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=25">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/2lsz30tp86skc4ckgo.jpeg" alt="Kuklica Smerek Architekti + Hubinský" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">Kuklica Smerek Architekti + Hubinský</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=27">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/1eviid0eh5hc0w80gk.jpeg" alt="KILO / HONČ" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">KILO / HONČ</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=29">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/vd2uv050nusgo8gs0.jpeg" alt="Langarita–Navarro: Temperamentný zmysel pre detail" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">Langarita–Navarro: Temperamentný zmysel pre detail</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=30">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/8ifuadcp36gws4440.jpg" alt="SINGULARCH: Langarita–Navarro (Madrid, ESP)" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">SINGULARCH: Langarita–Navarro (Madrid, ESP)</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=31">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/1ejmfi868dq88gwok.jpg" alt="KOSMOS: Európska profesionalita a ruský drive" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">KOSMOS: Európska profesionalita a ruský drive</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=32">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/26q2osyy6growccwwo.jpg" alt="SINGULARCH: KOSMOS (Moskva, RUS)" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">SINGULARCH: KOSMOS (Moskva, RUS)</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only added a `#loadMore` button, which was strangely missing... And a js line to hide all the `.more-box` from start.

Then, for the "reset" when there is no more hidden elements, the `if` condition was misplaced. You have to test this condition first.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(function() {
    
    // Hide them all
    $(".more-box").hide()
    
    $(".more-box").slice(0, 3).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      // If there is no hidden elements
      if($(".more-box:hidden").length ===0){
        $(".more-box").hide()
        $(".more-box").slice(0, 3).show();
      }
      
      // If there is at least one hidden element
      else{
        $(".more-box:hidden").slice(0, 3).fadeIn();
      }
      
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="articles">
  <div class="wrapper more-content">
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=26">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/c4slrsw6a680840g40.jpeg" alt="ov-a: Pedantný proces navrhovania v kombinácii s dialógom s klientom" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">ov-a: Pedantný proces navrhovania v kombinácii s dialógom s klientom</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=24">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/71c2l0vfphwc40c40s.jpeg" alt="SINGULARCH: ov–a (Praha, CZ)" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">SINGULARCH: ov–a (Praha, CZ)</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=25">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/2lsz30tp86skc4ckgo.jpeg" alt="Kuklica Smerek Architekti + Hubinský" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">Kuklica Smerek Architekti + Hubinský</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=27">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/1eviid0eh5hc0w80gk.jpeg" alt="KILO / HONČ" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">KILO / HONČ</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=29">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/vd2uv050nusgo8gs0.jpeg" alt="Langarita–Navarro: Temperamentný zmysel pre detail" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">Langarita–Navarro: Temperamentný zmysel pre detail</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=30">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/8ifuadcp36gws4440.jpg" alt="SINGULARCH: Langarita–Navarro (Madrid, ESP)" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">SINGULARCH: Langarita–Navarro (Madrid, ESP)</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=31">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/1ejmfi868dq88gwok.jpg" alt="KOSMOS: Európska profesionalita a ruský drive" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">KOSMOS: Európska profesionalita a ruský drive</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-box">
      <div class="margin-column equal_col">
        <a href="clanok.php?uid=32">
          <div class="image-wrapp"><img src="uploads/thumbs/26q2osyy6growccwwo.jpg" alt="SINGULARCH: KOSMOS (Moskva, RUS)" />
          </div>
          <p class="article-title">SINGULARCH: KOSMOS (Moskva, RUS)</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Added a button-->
<button id="loadMore">Load More</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for correction. But this isn't the solution what I'm looking for, when I click on the button when all divs are loaded nothings happen. :-(

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot. Happy new yeer!!! :-)